# Is There a Way to Block Adding Users to Azure Resources via Policy?

Tags: azure, rbac, azure-policy

Is There a Way to Block Adding Users to Azure Resources via Policy?

My organization wants to only allow Groups to be added to Azure Resources and not Users. Looking at the built in polices there doesn't seem to be a way to restrict this natively. So, is there a way to do this through a custom policy? Or by some other means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for interesting question :)

I think the way to go would be via policies as you said. Create policy which will deny any user role assignment.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/principalType",
          "equals": "User"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Then assign this policy to subscription you need.

[image: Result]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.authorization/roleassignments?tabs=json

Comment: Thank you for this. I was using Powershell (Get-AZRoleAssignments) and it was returning objectType for the User field. So, I was looking at the Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments properties but was looking for objectType not principalType. Glad to know I was on the right track. Thank you again.

Comment: Is this policy work? In my case no resource is affected although we have multiple users.